# Is it Possible to Fetch Users fro Github Api by users Location

Tags: git, github, github-api

Is it Possible to Fetch Users from Github Api by users Location?

this code below fetch users by their username :

```javascript
async getUser(user) {
    const profileResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}?client_id=${this.client_id}&client_secrets=${this.client_secret}`);

    const profile = await profileResponse.json();

    return {
        profile
    }
}
```

I am currently Working on a Github Api Project.

Comment: async getUser(user){
        const profileResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}?client_id=${this.client_id}&client_secrets=${this.client_secret}`);

        const profile = await profileResponse.json();

        return{
            profile
        }
    }                        // That code fetches on a Single User

Comment: Have you tried the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-users/#search-by-location)? Doesn't it [answer your question](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Github search users API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users) with `location` search term :

https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location:france

Using javascript :

```javascript
var country = "france";
fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${encodeURIComponent(`location:${country}`)}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```